# form-only lookup

Tags: informix, 4gl

How can I create a form-only look up in Informix 4GL? I am using form painter plus the informix SE. Any help would be appreciated. I tried to create the form but the field is empty while selecting the choice. I think I am missing the relation or something.

Answer (score 1):

FORMONLY is the equivalent of DISPLAYONLY in isql perform screens. Why not just define the database columns in the attributes section and use the NOUPDATE attribute for each column, or use BEFORE EDITUPDATE OF tabname, ABORT?

Answer (score 0):

Since I4GL doesn't come with a form painter, the only ways to know what you can do with it is by reading the manual for your form painter, or by experimenting.

I'm also not entirely sure what you mean by a FORMONLY lookup?  It could be any of a number of items.  But the basics are that the field in the form is `FORMONLY.fieldname TYPE xyz` where `xyz` is the appropriate type.  You use a CONSTRUCT or INPUT to get data into that field; you process the input to do the lookup.  INPUT is more appropriate for an exact value lookup; CONSTRUCT will allow more flexible querying.

Since you've not shown what you've tried, nor indicated which form painter you're using, it is going to be hard to help further.

(And I note you've asked this question on the IIUG ([International Informix Users Group](http://www.iiug.org/)) mailing list for 'classics' too.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using a fourGEN painter, what I did so far is; I created a lookup field, and I am at define lookups area there is three column 1 Lookup Name:stklook 2.Lookup Table: state, 3. Join Criteria : state.code=$state. but still I am missing something. any idea what I am missing???

Comment: I wondered if it was FourGen.  I've not used it for so long (15+ years, and I had hardly used it even back then) that I'm afraid I can offer no help.  It is built atop I4GL, but the programs it writes are very stylized, not what people would write on their own.  Don't get me wrong; it does a good job.  But it requires knowledge I don't have.

Comment: @TomJ: FORMONLY is the equivalent of DISPLAYONLY in isql perform screens. Why not just define the database columns in the attributes section and use the NOUPDATE attribute for each column, or use BEFORE EDITUPDATE OF tabname, ABORT?

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so can you accept it as the answer?